# What's the name of algorithm/field about positioning many small objects to form shapes?

Tags: algorithm

sorry that English is not my native language. I would like to know what's the name of the algorithm/field about positioning small objects to form shapes?

I don't know what's the term for it, so let me give some examples.
e.g.1. 
In cartoons, sometimes there will be a swarm of insects forming a skeleton head in the air

e.g.2. 
In the wars in the 1700s, infantry units are a bunch of men standing together, forming columns or ranks, changing shapes as the battle rage on.

e.g.3 
In opening ceremonies of Olympics, often there will be a bunch of dancers forming variou symbols on the field.

So bascally, numerous small objects beginning in arbitrary positions, moving to a new position such that they together form a shape in 2D or 3D.
What is such technique called?

Comment: sounds like a packing problem to me... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem

Answer (score 1):

In graphics, this would normally be called a "particle system" (and Googling for that should yield quite a few results that are at least *reasonably* relevant).

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the dancers/soldiers don't interfere when moving, then you can view the problem as a maximum matching problem.

For each person, you know their starting location, and you know the shape of the final pattern.  You probably want to minimize the total time it takes to form the final shape from the start shape.

You can determine if it's possible to go from an initial state from a start state in time T by forming a bipartite graph.  For each person and final position, if the person can reach the position in <= T, add an edge from the person to that position.  Then run a maximum matching algorithm to see if everyone can find some position in the final locations within the time constraint.

Do a binary search on the time T and you'll have the minimum amount of time to go from one state to another.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs

Comment: In some applications a minimum-cost matching may also be desirable.